# Showing a string as number with two decimal places

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

In my iOS app, I am receiving JSON data from a remote server. One of the fields value can be a double number, like 24.87,or an int number, like 24.
Now I want to show the number in a view, as label text, but I want always to get a 2 decimal places number, as example if the remote value is 24, I want to show 24.00...

I am using the following code to do it:

```
if ([tarifa_comanda isEqualToString:@"T1"]){
        cell.tarifa_label.text = @"T1";

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"precio1_plato"]];
        cell.precio_plato_label.text = myNumber;  

    }
```

But I am getting a wrong output from the number. This is what I am getting, the label is the one with the blue background:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the maximum and minimum number of fraction digits that you want your formatter to display by setting its maximumFractionDigits and minimumFractionDigits properties.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.342]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.3]]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0]]);
```

Comment: Thank you @mttcrsp, but the answer from ben was given first.

Comment: @mvasco But this is a MUCH better answer. Use this approach to make your users happy.

Comment: @rmaddy, using this answer I get the following outputs: If source value is 23.76, I am getting 0.00, if source value is 23, I am getting 23.00. Any help??

Comment: I've tested again using the inputs you mentioned and I'm not experiencing any bug. Try copy and pasting this NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:23.76]]);

Comment: Thanks @mttcrsp,but I need to use the value received from JSON, an it is a string value. What can I do to use your code using the value [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"precio1_plato"]];

Comment: @mttcrsp, I am using a simulator located in Spain and using ',' as decimal point, not '.' The value stored in the remote data base is 23.76, with '.' as decimal point.

Comment: To answer your first question try this NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"precio1_plato"]]);

Comment: To answer your second question, NSNumberFormatter automatically provides the right number representation for the country in which your app is localized. Example: If an american user will use your app he will see a dot since this is standard separator in the US, if a spanish or italian user use your app they will see a comma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64444/discussion-between-mttcrsp-and-mvasco).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your "myNumber" with
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [myNumber doubleValue]];

Comment: Thank you, but now it is showing an error: No visible @interface for 'NSNumber' declares the selector 'float'.

Comment: The correct selector is `floatValue`, but you might as well use `doubleValue` since a `float` will be promoted to `double` in this case.

Comment: Thank you @ben, it works with the correction made by robmayoff.

Comment: Do not use this answer. It doesn't properly format numbers based on the user's locale. The other answer using `NSNumberFormatter` is much better than this answer.